# How to identify recently changed SPs in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to get the list of stored procedures which were recently changed.

In MS SQL Server, there are system tables which store those information and we can easily retrieve what has changed. Similarly I want to find most recent changed SPs and tables in PostgreSql

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible, Postgres doesn't store that information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Could you explain what's not possible? An event trigger can at least detect a change.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: An event trigger would be a solution indeed. But that needs to be created _before_ you want to check this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EVENT TRIGGER for logging. More information about how to create and use event triggers, can be found in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createeventtrigger.html) and [www.youlikeprogramming.com](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2013/10/implementing-ddl-event-triggers-in-postgresql-9-3/).

You need at least version 9.3.